# GoogleService-Info.plist file not found and clientId was not provided programmatically

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried adding firebase to my flutter project using fluttefire command line tool. I am using Google Authentication service from firebase and calling `SignIn` function, it gives the following error. The ios folder has `GoogleService-Info.plist` file.

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(missing-config, GoogleService-Info.plist file not found and clientId was not provided programmatically., null, null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
    #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      GoogleSignInPlatform.initWithParams (package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/google_sign_in_platform_interface.dart:98:5)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:267:5)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:402:5)
```

Comment: I have the same problem how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using `flutterfire` command line tool to connect to firebase? This see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The FlutterFire command line tool generates a Dart file, so you don't need a `GoogleService-Info.plist`. Inserting a `GoogleService-Info.plist` although using the Command Line tool is redundant. However, you must also specify the generated options when initializing:

```
Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform)
```

Using `DefaultFirebaseOptions` is the new way for using Firebase with Flutter and the manual insertion of the configuration files is the old way.

EDIT: I didn't understand that this problem is about the `GoogleSignIn` plugin (I did not really read the stack trace ). In this case, the error is exactly the same as in the error message. You have not specified a client id:

```
GoogleSignIn(clientId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.iosClientId).signIn()
```

EDIT:
Yes, the new version of `flutterfire` also generates the corresponding files such as `GoogleService-Info.plist`, but you don't need these files anymore since the parameter `clientId` exists in the `GoogleSignIn` plugin.

Comment: I know that with the command line tool, manual addition is not required, but the auto-generated file did not work and gave the exception as mentioned above.

Comment: Understood now. But it's confusing because `flutterfire` also adds a `GoogleService-Info.plist` `file to ios/Runner`.

Comment: For sure? flutterfire shouldn't so this. I have no `GoogleService-Info.plist` in my projects and I'm using flutterfire.

Comment: Yes, that's what confused me, so I decided to add it manually after following similar issues on Github.

Comment: For some reason , my `DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.iosClientId` is not matching with the found in `GoogleService-Info.plist` `CLIENT_ID` - i needed to hardcode `GoogleSignIn(clientId: "key")`

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted that issues on github.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96248

And they said.

> google_sign_in plugin currently doesn't support dart-only
> initialization and for mean time, you'll need to fallback on manual
> installation.

31/Aug/2022, I still face the same problem

Comment: I actually fixed the issue by reading the doc and modifying the  `[my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist` file

Comment: @millerf how you solved the problem, could you give some details please?

Comment: @msalihbindak I don't quite remember in details, but I basically scraped all I did and followed the flutter_google_signin documentation line by line...

Comment: @msalihbindak I was facing the same problem even though I followed all the steps. It turned out that my GoogleService-Info.plist was not aimed at Runner. I.e., you just had to go to xcode, select GoogleService-Info.plist in the file tree and put the target Runner flag (on the right).

Answer (score 1):

Moving GoogleService-Info.plist file to the Runner folder solved it for me.